# SKlearn metrics fails with expected y object and predicted y object

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

In Sci-kit learn have created a few models with train and test data.

The models work fine, but when I try to compute any accuracy metrics, it fails. I assume something is wrong with either my prediction object (pred y) or expected object (true y).

For this test, I have looked at the pred y. It is an object and have 119 0/1 values.

The true y is also an object and has 119 0/1 values.

My code and the error is below, as well as an object comparison. It is the error I do not understand.

"expected" is my true y and "target_predicted" is the predicted y.

I have tried other metrics and other models- it always fails when I am at this stage.

Any assistance?

```
#Basic Decsion Tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(bank_train, bank_train_target)
print clf

DecisionTreeClassifier(compute_importances=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            random_state=None, splitter='best')

#test model using test data
target_predicted = clf.predict(bank_test)
accuracy_score(expected,target_predicted)


#error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-23d1a990a192> in <module>()
      1 #test model using test data
      2 target_predicted = clf.predict(bank_test)
----> 3 accuracy_score(expected,target_predicted)


/Users/mpgartland1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.pyc in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
   1295 
   1296     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
-> 1297     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   1298     if y_type == 'multilabel-indicator':
   1299         score = (y_pred != y_true).sum(axis=1) == 0

/Users/mpgartland1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.pyc in _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    125     if (y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator",
    126                        "multilabel-sequences"]):
--> 127         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
    128 
    129     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: unknown is not supported
```

Here is a comparison of the two objects.

```
print target_predicted.size
print expected.size
print target_predicted.dtype
print expected.dtype
print target_predicted
print expected

119
119
object
object
[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

If also fails when I try a confusion matrix or other metric- using very cookie cutter code. So, my guess is in the object(s).

Thanks

Comment: could you try making arrays out of your expected and predicted targets?

Comment: @eickenberg so I just created: target_predicted = np.array(clf.predict(bank_test)) and then did the same on expected. The data output looks the same and I get the same error. Hmm.

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: v.15 AND just for kicks- I then converted both to a Pandas dataframes and ended up with two 119 x 1. But still errors. Have to be missing something simple.

Comment: Wait, why is the `dtype` of your target and expected `object`?? That is fishy. It should be an integer type, or boolean or floats. This is pretty surely the reason why it isn't working for you. No need to convert to pandas dataframes, just figure out why you have dtype object there and change it.

Comment: @eickenberg Thanks. That got me on the right track to get it fixed. There goes a day....   Thanks again.